# File.directory? returns false because ENV["HOME"] contains path with Russian words

Tags: ruby

```
File.directory?(ENV["HOME"])
```

returns false because `ENV["HOME"]` contains path with Russian words, like:

```
c:/Users/Администратор
```

How do I solve it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not in English

Comment: @multiMessengerTelegram  Please ask question in English from next time.

Comment: @SandeepBiradar do not you translate from Russian using google translate..

Comment: Are you sure the value of ENV['HOME'] is a valid windows path?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be on Windows. Windows has the oddity, that upper- and lowercase file names are not distinguished (i.e. Windows remembers the case of the letters, when the entry is created, but it ignores case, when a filename is used). Ruby tries to mimic this, but I don't know whether it is able to to this "case-insensitivity" with cyrillic characters. Could it be that the directory had been created in a different spelling (with regard to upper/lower case), than it is stored in the ENV hash?

I would proceed as follows: From an `irb` shell, do a

```
Dir['c:/Users']
```

You should see the entries in the "correct" spelling. Does it exactly match the content of ENV['HOME']?  If you use copy and paste from this output, and ask (again in the `irb` shell) for `File.directory?('....')`, does it evaluate to `true` then?